# How to get a reverse index in ngFor angular?

Tags: angular

I am using the latest version of Angular and have an array "myarray" with 3 objects.

I want to make it so that I have divs looking like this:

```
<div id="num2">
<div id="num1">
<div id="num0">
```

Usually with *ngFor I do..

```
<div *ngFor="let something of myarray; let i = index" [attr.id]="'num'+i">
```

The problem is that creates an incrementally increasing so it is going from 0 to 2 instead of the reverse...

```
<div id="num0">
<div id="num1">
<div id="num2">
```

How can I make it such that it is decreasing?

Comment: Arithmetics: `myarray.length - i - 1`?

Comment: have tried using `count`?

Comment: Are you trying to loop through the array in reverse? Your question is unclear. To loop in reverse you could just do ```let something of myarray.reverse()```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
<div *ngFor="let something of myarray; let i = index;" 
     [attr.id]="'num' + (myarray.length - i - 1)">
```

Answer (score 5):

@nicholas-k Answer is also right, but I think the best way to do it is by using [count](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L17) provided by `ngFor` directive.

```
<div *ngFor="let something of myarray; let cnt = count; let i = index;" [attr.id]="'num' + ( cnt - i - 1 )">
```

Comment: Is it 'legal' to put the 1 inside of the condition (let i = count - index - 1)? I am getting a "Parser Error: Unexpected token 1, expected identifier, keyword, or string"

Comment: @Rolando my mistake, its not legal, let me correct that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a length of the myarray into a variable and then subtract it with the index

Like this declare a variable

```
myarrayLength ;
```

In the function in which the value is set

```
this.myarrayLength =myarray.length;
```

Then you can  subtract while in ng-for

```
<div *ngFor="let something of myarray; let i = index" [attr.id]="'num'+ (myarrayLength - i)">
```

Comment: Does it have to be put into a variable or could I just use myarr.length in the template?